# Accessing state value from StyleSheet.create in ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new in ReactNative and I have the following components:

```
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animated.Image style= {styles.photo}
              source={{uri: this.props.user.picture.large}}/>
    </View>
    <View style={{backgroundColor:'whitesmoke', flex: 1}}></View>
  </View>
```

In the styles, I have the following:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
  flex: 0.5,
  backgroundColor: '#4dbce9',
  alignItems: 'center',
 },
 photo: {
  height: 150,
  width: 150,
  borderRadius: 75,
  borderWidth: 3,
  borderColor: 'white',
  transform: [                        // `transform` is an ordered array
            {scale: this.state.profileImgBounceVal}, 
          ]
  }
});
```

I got an error when I access `this.state.profileImgBounceVal` as its outside the component I know. Is there any workaround for this except including the styles inside the `Animated.Image` tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`Stylesheet.flatten()`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html#flatten) to create a reusable style object in your component:

```
var animatedImageStyle = StyleSheet.flatten([
  styles.photo,
  {
    transform: [{scale:this.state.profileImgBounceVal}]
  }
])

<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Animated.Image style={animatedImageStyle}
            source={{uri: this.props.user.picture.large}}/>
  </View>
  <View style={{backgroundColor:'whitesmoke', flex: 1}}></View>
</View>
```