# Accessing variables defined in component state in StyleSheet.create? (undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.filterMenuHeight'))

Tags: react-native

I want to animate the entry of a component.

So I defined an animated variable in my component state.

But when trying to refer to it from StyleSheet.create I get the undefined is not an object error.

This is my component code:

I tried replacing this.state.filterMenuHeight with .state.filterMenuHeight, but still getting the same error.

I can access variables if they are defined in an external file though.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
    Animated,
    StyleSheet,
    Button,
    StatusBar,
    View,
    TextInput,
    Text,
    Keyboard,
    Platform,
    FlatList
} from 'react-native'
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'
import Modal from 'react-native-modalbox'
import Modal2 from'react-native-swipe-up-down'
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation'

import ScreenName from './ScreenName'
import ScreenNames from '../constants/ScreenNames'
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';
import FilterMenu from './FilterMenu';

export default class RequestBulletin extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this)

        this.state = {
            titleFilterText: "",
            scrollOffsetY: 0,
            filterMenuHeight: new Animated.Value(0) 
        }

        this.data = [
            <View key="1" style={styles.item}/>,
            <View key="2" style={styles.item}/>,
            <View key="3" style={styles.item}/>,
            <View key="4" style={styles.item}/>,
            <View key="5" style={styles.item}/>,
            <View key="6" style={styles.item}/>,
            <View key="7" style={styles.item}/>,
            <View key="8" style={styles.item}/>,
            <View key="9" style={styles.item}/>,
            <View key="10" style={styles.item}/>, 
            <View key="11" style={styles.item}/>, 
            <View key="12" style={styles.item}/> 
        ]
    }

    handleScroll = function(event) {
        this.setState({scrollOffsetY:event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style ={styles.container}>

                <View style={{flexDirection:'row', marginLeft:20,marginRight:20}}>
                    <TextInput 
                        style={{flex:1, height: 40, marginRight:10, borderWidth:1, borderColor: Colors.GrayAccent, borderRadius:5}} 
                        onChangeText={(titleFilterText) => this.setState({titleFilterText})}
                    />
                    <Icon 
                        type='font-awesome' 
                        name="sliders" 
                        size={25} 
                        color={Colors.GrayAccent}
                        onPress={()=> {this.refs.modal1.open()}}
                    />
                </View>

                <Text>
                    {this.state.scrollOffsetY}
                </Text>
                <ScreenName ScreenName="Bullentin"/>
                <Button
                    title = "Dashboard"
                    onPress = {() => {
                        props.navigation.navigate(ScreenNames.Dashboard, {
                            calledFrom : ScreenNames.Bulletin
                        })    
                    }}
                    style = {{width: '200'}}
                />

                <Animated.View 
                    style={styles.filterMenu}
                >
                    <FlatList
                    style= {{flex:1, width: '100%'}}
                    data= {this.data}
                    renderItem = {({item}) => item}
                    onScroll={this.handleScroll}
                    />  
                </Animated.View>

            </SafeAreaView>
        );
  }
}

let styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : StatusBar.currentHeight,
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width:'100%'

    },
    filterMenu: {
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: 'pink',
        opacity: .6,
        width: '100%',
        bottom: 40,
        height: this.state.filterMenuHeight
    },
    item: {
        height: 80,
        width:'100%',
        margin: 10,
        marginRight: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
})
```

Right now I am making it work using this:

```
<Animated.View style={[styles.filterMenu, { height: this.state.filterMenuHeight }]}
>
  <FlatList
   style= {{flex:1, width: '100%'}}
   data= {this.data}
   renderItem = {({item}) => item}
   onScroll={this.handleScroll}
  />  
</Animated.View>
```

#### I know this question is similar to another question

[Accessing state value from StyleSheet.create in ReactNative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735784/accessing-state-value-from-stylesheet-create-in-reactnative)

But the issue with the answer there is that it's very similar to my fix. Essentially 2 different style sheets are squished into one.
This will quickly become inefficient it the number of objects to style is more than 1.

So can what I want to do be done without StyleSheet.flatten()?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing state value from StyleSheet.create in ReactNative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735784/accessing-state-value-from-stylesheet-create-in-reactnative)

Comment: @Isaac I saw that code. But If I am understanding that approach correct, then I will have to create a flattened version for each style I want to assign. If I had, say 10 components, then that method would quickly become annoying. Also what he did is essentially very similar to my current fix. Combining 2 different styles. But I wanted to know if there was another way that was more scalable.

Comment: `Flattens an array of style objects, into one aggregated style object` https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet

Comment: Means just place all your style into that array, and flatten will compute into a style object that is reusable

Comment: @Isaac yeah I got how it works. But don't you think it's rather inefficient way to solve this issue?

Comment: `StyleSheet.create` simply not belongs to your `RequestBulletin` component and hence couldn't access the state. You only have two options, one is as you've mentioned in your question, another is `stylesheet.flatten`.

Comment: I guess you are right. Sucks that I can't directly access it even when using the class name.